# How to deploy .bin files from Visual Studio project?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm making windows application in VB.NET and I added some files in my project in solution explorer and I set on every file I added

> "Copy to Output Directory: Copy Always"

but it deploy every file except .bin files after publishing. 
  It work in debugging mode, but not when I publish it. any help please, how to deploy .bin files?
  Thanks.

Comment: what files did you include and how did you deploy?

Comment: I added .bin files to project  and just pressed build and publish , it deploy every file except .bin files

Comment: How are you deploying it?

Comment: Visual Studio deployed it, I just added files and set copy always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the `Build Action` property of those files set to? If it is `Content` then I believe that they should be included in the deployment automatically. If not, open the Publish page of the project properties and click the Application Files button. There you can control what files are included in the ClickOnce deployment.